# jQuery - Get table row count with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can get the number of rows in an HTML table with the following jQuery:

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr').length;
```

However, how can I get the number of rows that have a given class (e.g., `<tr class="MyClass>`). How can I count the number of rows in a table with a class of "MyClass"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply add the class to the selector

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody tr.MyClass').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to overqualify so this would work too

```
var rows= $('#myTable tbody .MyClass').length;
```

Comment: Depends on what the meaning of the class is.  If it's a class that is only ever applied at the row level, then yes.  If it's a class that means "flagged" or "updated recently" or something and is potentially applied at both row and cell level then you won't get the same answer...  Probably best not to mix the class like this, but you can.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam said use .class-name selector.
For further examples see [other jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jQuery to check for instances of the class.

```
var rows = $('.MyClass').length;
```

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ma7pz/